# when i subscribe my Observable, my next is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscription

```
myObservable():Observable<boolean>{
  const result = new Subject<boolean>();
  result.next(true);
  result.complete();
  return result.asObservable();
}

this.myObservable().subscribe(x=> console.log(x));
```

when i subscribe my Observable which function name is myObservable
but the console never working

```
this.myObservable().subscribe({
next: _response => {console.log('next');}
        error: error => {
            console.log('had an error');
       },
       complete: () => {
           console.log('complete');
           this.accountDataLoaded = true;
       }})
```

try the life cycle console
the complete was print but next is not

Comment: You next is the actual function you pass  in the subscribe function

Comment: Because you return an Observable that is already complete ?

Comment: but i delete complete() still dont working
my understanding is when i subscribe observable will trigger next()
and the boolean will console

Comment: @IanWang `complete()` is not relevant here. It is used to unsubscribe the subscribers and forbids to emit new values on the `Subject`. The main problem is that the code subscribes the `Subject` after the emission of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does :

- Create an `Observable`
- Emit a value : `true`
- Complete the `Observable`
- return the `Observable`
- Subscribe to the next values from the `Observable`

Of course, no new values are emitted. That is why the callback will never be executed.

As an example, you can use a timeout if you want to emit the values after the subscription :

```js
function myObservable():Observable<boolean>{
  const result = new Subject<boolean>();
  setTimeout(() => {
    result.next(true);
    result.complete();
  }, 1000)
  return result.asObservable();
}
this.myObservable().subscribe(x=> console.log(x));
```

But, as you created a `Subject`, you could also use a [ReplaySubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject) which emits old values to new subscribers

```js
function myObservable():Observable<boolean>{
  const result = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
  result.next(true);
  result.complete();
  return result.asObservable();
}

this.myObservable().subscribe(x=> console.log(x));
```